# Property in Data is undefined inside methods() method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm brand new to Vue so trying to understand the basics so far. I'm using Vue 3.

My intention is to:

- Create a select with the items in the array as options, this works.
- Once the button is clicked, store the value of the select, this also works.
- Push an object using the value of the select as an object's key's value

It's at this final stage that the error occurs, specifically the line `getGeneMutationData: () => this.queryConstraints.push({`

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'queryConstraints')
    at Proxy.getGeneMutationData (Query.vue?12c2:46:14)
    at eval (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?3191:380:1)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?a261:155:1)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?a261:164:1)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?a261:174:1)
    at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?3191:366:39)
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working, based on the documentation I'm not sure what's different in the approaches:

```
data() {
    return { count: 4 }
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      // `this` will refer to the component instance
      this.count++
    }
  }
```

Here's a minimised of my code:

```
<template>
  <select v-model="selectedGeneMutation">
    <option v-for="geneMutation in geneMutations" :key="geneMutation">{{geneMutation}}</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" @click="getGeneMutationData">Get results</input>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Home',
    data: () => ({
      geneMutations: ['ACTC',
                      'MYBPC3'
      ],
      queryConstraints: [],
      selectedGeneMutation: ''
    }),
    setup() {},
    methods: {
      getGeneMutationData: () => this.queryConstraints.push({
        fieldPath: this.selectedGeneMutation,
        opStr: '==',
        value: true
      })
    }
  };
</script>
```

Any help as to why I can't access the properties in 'data' would really be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using an [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). It's limited and doesn't have its own binding to `this`, that's why your method fails. The documentation you're referring to is using a traditional function expression.

So in your case try this:

```
getGeneMutationData: function () {
  this.queryConstraints.push({
  fieldPath: this.selectedGeneMutation,
  opStr: "==",
  value: true,
});
```

EDIT: Actually Nikola Pavicevic's answer is correct. Yes, using a traditional function expression solves your problem, however, it seems like mixing up composition and options API (or rather not understanding the difference between the two) is what caused the issue in the first place. In Vue 3, when you use [composition API](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html) you're not using `this`. The `setup()` method returns an object, and all of its properties are exposed to the rest of the component.

Comment: This was what was wrong! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should not mix composition and options API (`this` is not the same, also, there is no methods in composition API), try like following snippet (composition API) or you can move your methods to options API (remove `setup` function):

```js
const { ref } = Vue
const App = {
  setup() {
    const geneMutations = ref(['ACTC', 'MYBPC3'])
    let queryConstraints = ref([])
    const selectedGeneMutation = ref('')
    const getGeneMutationData = () =>  {
      queryConstraints.value.push({
        fieldPath: selectedGeneMutation.value,
        opStr: '==',
        value: true
      })
    }
    return {  
      geneMutations, queryConstraints, selectedGeneMutation, getGeneMutationData
    };
  }
}
Vue.createApp(App)
  .mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.29/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selectedGeneMutation">
    <option v-for="geneMutation in geneMutations" :key="geneMutation">{{geneMutation}}</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" @click="getGeneMutationData" value="Get results" />
  <h3>{{ queryConstraints }}</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: This wasn't what was wrong but thank you! I wasn't aware you shouldn't mix them and I have now gone out my way to stop doing this